# How to pass injection token to nested service using SCAM approach (Single Component Angular Module)?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-module, injection-tokens

I have been playing with **SCAM** (Single Component Angular Modules) approach and I am facing a problem passing **injection token** from parent to child module.

I have a **ScamService** with **httpClient** and **baseUrl** injected:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, Inject, NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { BASE_URL } from './injection.tokens';

@Injectable()
export class ScamService {
  constructor( @Inject(BASE_URL) private baseUrl, private httpClient: HttpClient ) {}

  public getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get(`${this.baseUrl}/rest-of-endpoint`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [HttpClientModule]
})
export class ScamServiceModule {
  public static forRoot(baseUrl): ModuleWithProviders<ScamServiceModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: ScamServiceModule,
      providers: [{
          provide: BASE_URL,
          useValue: baseUrl
      }]
    };
  }
}
```

To provide **BASE_URL** token to a module I need to create static method that returns **ModuleWithProviders**. There i am able to assign a value to the token. That's fine.

Next, I want to use the service in a component, so I am importing **ScamServiceModule** into **ScamComponentModule**:

```
import { Component, ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ScamService, ScamServiceModule } from './scam.service';

@Component({//...})
export class ScamComponent {
  constructor(private scamService: ScamService) {}
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ScamServiceModule.forRoot(
      `The url I would like to pass is not in the environments, 
       I need to take it from forRoot of ScamComponentModule`
    )
  ]
})
export class ScamComponentModule {
  public static forRoot(baseUrl): ModuleWithProviders<ScamComponentModule> {
    // how to tell ScamServiceModule what the value of baseUrl is?
  }
}
```

Now I need to provide base url to it. So I should call **ScamServiceModule.forRoot('some-url')**. That would be fine If I knew the url on the component level.

But the url needs to be passed through **forRoot** method of **ScamComponentModule**.

Do you have any suggestion on how to pass the baseUrl through?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with SCAM approach.

It`s just about providing dependencies. The solution to the problem is to use 'deps' property, alongside 'provide' and 'useValue' in Angular Providers array.